# jQuery plugin relates to formating a dropdown list (select tag)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I did look up on the Internet for a plugin that allows me display data like this image shows:

[image]

There many plugins can help me show the checkbox like that, but the problem is to implement the tree-structure. When Click on the plus sign, it expands the content of Aldult category.
And when we click on the minus sign, the content of Movie category will be hidden.

Anyone knows which jquery plugin can do these requirements?

Thanks so much!

Khuong.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [jquery-steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/).  This plugin allows for multi-stage forms, which is what I believe you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks . But when I see its examples, I don't see the one that I need :(

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what information exactly you are needing in each dropdown?  As well as the "plus" sections, with checkboxes?  If you can give some sort of hierarchical tree, I could try to create a fiddle for you.  I see the image, and the first section is "User ID".  So, the second question is what type of submit function are you needing?  You may find a plugin to support multi-stage trees, but what type of data is needing to be passed upon user completion? If you can provide some more detail to the community, we can probably provide you with a solution.

Comment: Hi,
Below is the details about what I am developing:
-In the first dropdown list, select a UserID
-In the second one, if you select "Main Category",the last dropdown list will be disabled.
  If you select "Sub category", the 4th dropdown list will be enabled, it contains list of MAIN CATEGORIES,shows them as
  a tree,each Main Cate is a node.
  When you click on every "node"(e.g: Adult),it will show the sub-cate of Adult -like expanding this node.
  If sub-categories are shown, when you click on Adult again, they will be hidden-like collapsing this node.
That's it. Plz help.